# Shared javascript resources between Node.js and Apache/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, apache, node.js

I am building a website which uses Apache + PHP on port 80 for the frontend, and Node.js + Socket.IO for dynamic updates on port 3000. There are quite a few shared Javascript resources between the two and I'd like to know how I can share them.

Here's my project layout:

```
project/
    www/                 // Apache DocumentRoot
        index.php
        js/              // Javascript files for the HTML pages
        css/
    app/
        App.php          // All the PHP files
    node/
        node_modules/    // Node modules installed by NPM
        app.js           // Node.js application
```

When my PHP application generates HTML code, it needs to put some `<script>` tags in `<head>` for things like underscore.js, backbone.js, socket.io.js, etcerea. But these scripts are all somewhere in de `node_modules` directory.

I have seen various examples but most use Node.js to serve the HTML page as well (usually using the express framework). So, they generate script includes like `/socket.io/socket.io.js`. But in my case I have two servers running on two ports.

So, how can I load the proper Javascript files without manually copying things from the `node_modules` directory to the `js` directory under the DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- Create a symlink (pointing from www/js to node_modules)
- Create an Apache2 alias in you Apache configuration file (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias))

If you have access to your Apache2 configuration, the 2nd solution is probably the better one. When going for the symlink solution, make sure you double-check the ownership of the folders if you experience problems.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the correct one. In the end I chose a different solution though. I am now using Phing as a build system and I simply have it copy the files over to the correct directories (and minify them at the same time).